# redux-simple-router - perform action based on URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I'm using Redux with redux-simple-router.

Here's what I'm trying to do. A user hits a URL like so:
`http://localhost:3000/#/profile/kSzHKGX`
Where `kSzHKGX` is the ID of the profile. This should route to Profile container filled out with the details of the profile with id `kSzHKGX`.

My routes look like this:

```
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    ...
    <Route path="profile" component={Profile} />
    ...
  </Route>
)
```

So hitting the above link would give me `Warning: [react-router] Location "undefined" did not match any routes`

My container looks like this:

```
@connect(
  state => state.profile,
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)
export class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { getProfileIfNeeded, dispatch } = this.props
    getProfileIfNeeded()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
      ...
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

So normally my container would just be populated from the state as usual in Redux.

Basically I need to have a way of doing some wildcard in the route. Than I need to pass the URL to the action that would pull up the right profile from an API. The question is, is it doable with react-simple-router? Can I do that somehow using UPDATE_PATH? Would it be the proper Redux way? Or should I use something else?

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with your Router configuration because you should not be getting `undefined` - perhaps the wrong or missing history? You might want to share that too. But for your URL, you'll need to define a path like `profile/:id` and then your component will receive a `params` object in its props that has the id of the profile you need.

Comment: What do you want to see in terms of history? </newb question> Now when I do the route as profile/:id, the app issues a request to the API to `http://localhost:5000/profiles/undefined` (???)

Comment: I meant how you're using a `history` library. E.g. the [basic demo](https://github.com/rackt/redux-simple-router/blob/master/examples/basic/app.js) works out of the box, so how does yours differ? Can we see your implementation? And if log `this.props` on your `Profile` component, what do you see?

Comment: I'm using this boilerplate app: https://github.com/anorudes/redux-easy-boilerplate . History comes with it, I didn't change anything there. Yes, I do see the param.id in the props. So it's pretty clear to me what to do at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Josh David Miller's advice, I made my route look like so:

```
<Route path="admin/profile/:id" component={Profile} />
```

Than my container got this method to get the profile from API:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { getProfile, dispatch } = this.props
  getProfile(this.props.params.id)
}
```

And this to cleanup (without it I would have the previous profile display for split second on component load - before I hit API in `componentWillMount`)

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.props.unmountProfile()
}
```

**Update:**

As an alternative to the cleanup, I'm considering using the [Container Component Pattern](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.6b457o6uh). Basically have the outer component do the data fetching and passing the data to the inner component as a prop.