# How to get parameters from hash URL with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Any method to get URL parameters from a HASH URL with react-router.

Comment: which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: you could do something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666087/redux-simple-router-perform-action-based-on-url ?

Comment: Tried it, but didn't work used a regex to extract the data I wanted ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to access the location in your `<Route>` Component via `this.props.location` and pass it down to child components as described in the *v2.0.0 Upgrade Guide*: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#accessing-location

**location docs:**
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/docs/Glossary.md#location